# Samsung 830 Series vs 840 Series

Tags: ssd

I am fairly new in the world of SSD.
I have a few questions.

1) I have a Dell XPS 14 laptop which I bought 2 years ago. Win 7, Intel Core i7, 8GB Ram, 2GB Graphics. I am wondering whether it will have the capability to support a SSD?

2) My hard disk is dying, I am going to replace it with either a Samsung 830 or 840. Not going for 840 Pro (Too pricey). So I am wondering which one will be better? In terms of specs between both drives, http://www.anandtech.com/show/6337/samsung-ssd-840-250gb-review/5

Thanks,
Venn.

Comment: 1) SSD use the same interface as HDDs: SATA. The only problem could be the size. Some SSDs are a bit thicker than standard laptop SSDs. 2) The 840 is faster, but more expensive. Which one you should buy is up to you. Shopping recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: I did a bit of research and it seems that the comparison between 830 vs 840 are more. 840 is excellent in read but extremely poor in write and it has poor endurance. 830 is very balance and good in all read, write and endurance. This is due to the fact that 840 is using NAND TLC and 830 NAND MLC.

Comment: [This review from AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6337/samsung-ssd-840-250gb-review/13) disagrees. While it's true that sequential reads are much slower on the 840, this isn't an issue for most use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tech Report reviewed the Samsung 840 series and concluded with:

> Those expecting the Samsung 840 Series to be a true successor to the 830 Series will no doubt be disappointed. The new drive is slower than its predecessor overall and quite sluggish with both sequential and random writes. Samsung's use of TLC memory is almost certainly to blame for the slower write performance, but the firm hasn't bet the farm on triple-stuffed NAND. The 840 Pro is the true follow-up to the 830 Series, and it features MLC chips with two bits per cell. Of course, the Pro also costs 50% more than the 840 Series. Clearly, it's a different class of drive.

Personally, I'd get the 830 over the (non-pro) 840.

You can read the full review [here](http://techreport.com/review/23887/samsung-840-series-ssd-reviewed).

Comment: I would like to go for the 830 Series as well. However it seems that most of the retailers here in New Zealand only do 840 now.

Answer (score 2):

Go with the 840 Pro Series. They have the better NAND MLC like the 830 Series.

The regular 840 Series I would advise against.